# Clean Local DB Even app not running or killed

Tags: android, sqlite, service

Is there any way to configure a service to be run after a particular timestamp i.e. on every 36 hours? how can we restart the same service, if user killed the app or service explicitly? How can we do the same on Android O (8.0), as there is limit put-up on background services by Android System. Please suggest me any solution.

Comment: see [Schedule tasks with WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Work Manager to do your job, You can schedule the task of cleaning your database and no matter if your app is running or not work manager will run after the defined time and cleanup your database.
You can read more about work manager from here
1. [Work manager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/)

Second Option you can use Job Scheduler if you don't want to use Work Manager
and in last you can use legacy Alarm Manager to do your job.

I would recommend using work manager as it has all the components ready off the shelf for you, it handles platforms and performs work on device according to their support.

Comment: Is Work Manager in release mode?

Comment: Yes, It is part of JetPack